# What is the proper way to check for nulls when accessing attributes of attributes of attributes?

Tags: java, coding-style, nullpointerexception

In the common situation where classes are embedded as attributes of other classes, what is the best way to check for nulls?

To illustrate what I'm talking about, say I want to access `this.getObject1().getObject2().someMethod()` where `getObject1()` or `getObject2()` could return `null`.  Right now I am doing the following, and it's ugly, and there has to be a better way:

```
if (this.getObject1() != null)
        if (this.getObject1().getObject2() != null)
            if (this.getObject1().getObject2().someMethod())
                return whatever;
```

To avoid a NPE, I have to check for nulls at each step before accessing someMethod().  What is a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: While not 100% related, you might want to consider reading up on the Null Object pattern as it may relate to your code in some fashion. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern#Java

Comment: This style is to be avoided as far as possible - see http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask - though I appreciate that library or legacy code may not leave you much option...

Comment: You don't need `this.` in front of method invocations.

Comment: sorry, my fault, null-safe-navigation wasn't released with this version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This style is to be avoided as far as possible - see the [Law of Demeter](http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask) - though I appreciate that library or legacy code may not leave you much option.

Functional programming languages (in particular) avoid this problem through the use of `Option` or `Maybe` objects, which can be used in Java to some extent. See [this article](http://blog.tackley.net/2010/09/option-in-scala-vs-null-in-java.html), for example. Long sequences of null checks can be avoided concisely using Scala for-comprehensions, for eaxmple. But back to Java...

Ideally, assuming you can modify the code you are calling, you would restructure so you can call the 'outer' object, which will then call the 'inner' object, with only one null check at each stage. Or restructure the code to avoid such deep nesting.

Comment: I like the "Tell, Don't Ask" concept, and I'll keep it in mind, but to avoid NPEs, you kinda have to ask the object if its attribute is null before accessing that attribute's attributes, right?  There's no way to "let the object handle it" if the object is null.

Comment: One approach is to create a special "Null Object" that you store instead of an actual null value. In other words you have a superclass or interface, with one or more "real" subclasses, and a special-case "null subclass" that can respond to calls safely.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to set the result of each method to variable, so that you don't have to re-call the method each time. So, something like this

```
Object obj1 = this.getObject1();
if (null != obj1)
{
    Object obj2 = obj1.getObject2();
    if (null != ob2)
    {
         Object obj3 = obj2.someMethod();
         if (null != obj3)
               return whatever;
    }
}
```

If the methods aren't expensive, you could opt for less code by doing it all within the same `if` like Chris Nava's solution

Comment: This is probably an improvement (although the answer could be worded better.) EDIT: Much better.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion.  I'm not sure that this improves readability enough to justify the extra lines of code,though.  It's kind of a toss up.

Answer (score 2):

I use && in place of the nested if()s.  It's only slightly cleaner (arguably) and still not what I would like.

```
if (
    this.getObject1() != null
    &&
    this.getObject1().getObject2() != null
    &&
    this.getObject1().getObject2().someMethod()
  ) {
            return whatever;
}
```

Comment: If getting the objects is [relatively] cheap and pure (as in the result is the same) .. this is the approach I'd immediately lean towards, but I prefer to put one expression on the same line after each `&&` ;-) Although in general I'd try to avoid the situation entirely ..

Comment: I agree.  The above assumes that the get() lookups are relatively inexpensive.  If not, then local variables with nested if()s are a better choice.  I also agree that the entire situation is a code smell.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify it more (at least easier to read) like:

```
Object o1 = getObject1();
if(o1 != null)
{
    Object o2 = getObject2();
    if(o2 != null)
    {
        if(o2.someMethod()) return whatever;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't much you can do. I mean, you could assign each step to a variable, but it'll just end up being more code, and you *could* write a generic method to do it using reflection, but it'll be much less performant for not really any good reason.